# Separate row data and get them in a table

Tags: microsoft-excel

On each row I have data like:
435;#eftertext;#375;#ansvarig utgivare

Above have two tags "eftertext", "ansvarig utgivare" separated by ";". I want to get rid of the numbers/id.

I have in total two columns with this data "column A" and "Column B".

I want a simple bar chart to see the AMOUNT of each tag, from both columns. I need to somehow separate each tag after the ";" and also I want to get rid of the numbers/ID.

How to do it in a simple way?

Answer (score 0):

Excel has a built-in function to allow users to split text like yours into columns for normal processing.

To use it follow this method:

1. Highlight the column containing your data.
2. Click the Data tab then click on the option called "Text to columns"
3. Select the "Delimited" option and click next
4. In the delimiters list, tick the "semicolon" option then click Finish

[image]